# What is the role of `decoder_input_ids`in the huggingface T5 model?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers

In particular,

1. Are these the ids of the tokens that have been already generated by the decoder?
2. Are these the tokens that should be generated by the decoder?

Then what are the logits of the forward function, are these the logits of the tokens that should follow the tokens of case 1.?